# How to import data from Google Spreadsheet into a Wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The title essentially says it all, but to clarify, my goal is to use a Google Spreadsheet (that has an online published form) to enter data into the post_meta of a Wordpress post.  It should be noted that I have created custom metaboxes to add customization to the wp-admin post editor.

Even further, is there a way to create a new post if a new entry is submitted to the Google Form that is linked with the Google Spreadsheet?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advanced,

A. Tate Barber

Comment: Have you tried any plugin like GData Importer or googled the topic ??

Comment: you will need to do something with this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/